# nodejs and Microsoft Graph API

Tags: node.js, axios, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to be able to send requests to the graph API from nodejs.
For that I followed the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-console
I manage to get a token that allows me to execute a request on the endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users with insomnia. I have the list of users of the tenant in JSON.
But in JS the response.data is unreadable (▼♦
��KK♥...), I tried to change the encoding but without success.

The tutorial uses the axios library and the get method to get the result, is it necessary to add something to get a json?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Accept-Encoding` with `application/json` in axios.get header.

Using this option for `axio` get call
at [Add a method to call a web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-console) section

```
    const options = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json'
        }
    };
```

It is [known defect](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298).

The default of it is gzip in axios v1.2.0

File structure
copy three files from tutorial
And modify `Axios` option part
[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "answer89",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "bin/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-node": "^1.14.4",
    "axios": "^1.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "yargs": "^17.6.2"
  }
}
```

.env

```
# Credentials
TENANT_ID={your tenant id}
CLIENT_ID={your client id}
CLIENT_SECRET={your secret}

# Endpoints
AAD_ENDPOINT=https://login.microsoftonline.com
GRAPH_ENDPOINT=https://graph.microsoft.com
```

CLIENT_ID - order is flipped in UI

TENANT_ID

[image]

CLIENT_SECRET
[image]

Check permission in your app - User.Read
[image]

Check owner is you
[image]

Run it in Terminal

```
npm install
node . --op getUsers
```

Finally run it got JWT(Access token) in Axios Header even if code ' ERR_BAD_REQUEST`

[image]

Comment: as soon as I add the encoding for json I get the error: "HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed" as response.data.

Comment: HTTP Error 400 means bad URL. What is URL in Axios get call?

Comment: I used the example of the microsoft tutorial, the endpoint in axios.get is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Comment: I tested the tutorial and can get the Access Token  and update my answer.

Comment: I think URL `https://graph.microsoft.com` is correct but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes with the tutorial we can get a token, the bad request is the result of the function callApi(endpoint, accessToken). But with this token and the same endpoint it's possible to get right response with postman or insomnia.

Answer (score 1):

I abandoned axios and use directly the fetch API with success. There is something not clear with Axios usage.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).